# Get same section of two objects in different type

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I'd like to find best practice for getting the same section of two objects

```
const firstObject = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
const secondObject = { 1, 2 }
// desired result: { a: 1, b: 2} or simply { a, b }
```

In my opinion, we need to do three steps:

1) Get value all values of each object

```
Object.values = Object.values || (obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]))
```

2) Find the same section from two arrays value
3) Find key-value pair from `firstObject`

Any other ways to do it?

Using [Standard built-in objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) as [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) or [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) is preferable

Comment: `const secondObject = { 1, 2 }` is not valid. Are you trying to create an array, or and object such as `{ 1: 1, 2: 2 }`

Comment: So did you try out your steps and get the result you were looking for?

Comment: Two `Number`s tagged with e.g. `{age: 33}` and `{size: 33}` are of different type and hence not comparable. Please get your types right before comparing their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the `firstObject` into `[key, value]` pairs using Object#entries (or polyfill), and use Array#reduce to combine all those that exist in the `secondObject`.

```js
const firstObject = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
const secondObject = { 1: 1, 2: 2 };


const result = Object.entries(firstObject).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
  value in secondObject && (obj[key] = value);
  
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain your source for more details.
As far as I know, `Object.entries(firstObject)` would return two arrays are `[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]` and `[ 1, 2, 3]`. 

And the first time `reduce callback`called we have key = a, value = 1.
How can source set value for `obj` here?

Comment: `value in secondObject && (obj[key] = value);` I don't understand why `&&` can set value to obj here.

Comment: Is it the same as `if ( value in secondObject ) {
    obj[key] = value
  }` ??

Comment: The result is similar. It's a Boolean if - if the 1st expression is true, the 2nd (assignment) will be called as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(firstObject).filter(key=> key in secondObject).reduce((o,k)=>(o[k]=firstObject[k],o),{});
```